# Self-hosted Disposable Email Services

Tags: email

`Spamgourmet` offers the source code for their service for people who want to run their own disposable email service. Are there any others available for download?

I'd prefer them to be written in PHP but I'm mostly just curious to see other options out there.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn’t be too tough to write in PHP, have a look at [Stack Overflow for a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=self+hosted+email), but this is what I would do.

I would create an actual email address with a catch all alias associated to it. Then in MySQL I would create the email addresses that I want to receive mail to.

So I would have:
anon-23432434@mydomain.com
anon-44655654@mydomain.com
(you can name them whatever you want)

When someone sends email to any of these addresses, it would go to the catchall@mydomain.com email address and sit in the inbox.

Next create a PHP script that can use POP to read emails and delete them from the server (I think PHP has built in functions for this). The script would check the send to address and look it up in your database. Then I could forward it to the right recipient (this is what Craigslist does), or it could be more elaborate and put the message in your database for an internal messaging system (sort of like LinkedIn or Facebook).

Not that tough to build at all.

Answer (score 1):

A google search found [many solutions](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Self-hosted+Disposable+Email+Services). Here is [one](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/email-systems/web-based-email/).